# Facebook Messenger App Invalid Scope - permission: pages_messaging_subscriptions

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-page, facebook-messenger

I'm attempting to connect a Facebook Messenger App to one of my pages..
I've connected Facebook Messenger Apps to pages before.

But this is the first time I've received this error...

[image]

What gives?

Comment: Have you found any solution to this. I am also stuck here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/281723762198561/) and we are currently working on it. In the meantime, please use our beta tier or generate the page access token through our API. To use the beta tier, you can access the following:

> https://developers.beta.facebook.com/apps/89000000000000/messenger/

Answer (score 2):

we got same error and here is helpful answer 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/281723762198561/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my app was live which was preventing access token generation.

Just go to app dashboard and disable the live checkbox as below:

[image]